# Why use of asymmetric power supply in Op Amps for this audio device?

Tags: power-supply, operational-amplifier, amplifier, audio

I am learning about op amps and audio devices, and decided to run a simulation of the following device:
https://www.electrosmash.com/klon-centaur-analysis

I started humble, and run the simulation in just one section of the circuit: The tone control.
When running the simulation in QSpice, I noted that the output signal has an offset. After a bit of fiddling with values, I found that this is caused by the asymmetry in the power supply (according to the schematic it's -8.6V and 16.2V)
When I set the values to be something like -8.6V and +8.6V, the signals centers properly at 0V.

What's the reason of these voltages in this particular situation?

I noticed that the same asymmetry is used in the Summing stage, as well as the gain stage, where the opAmp is set between ground and 9V

Note: There as very good chance that I am setting the model incorrectly in the simulation
[image]

Simulation:
[image]

Comment: *I noted that the output signal has an offset* What was the value of that offset?

Comment: I have attached the output of such circuit.

Answer (score 4):

At DC (where your offset lives) C1 can be disregarded. Also R1, R2, R5 and R6 are a simple chain between two sources of near-zero impedance, and so they won't affect input or output potentials in any way. They can also be disregarded.

What you are left with is:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fKYGrg.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The relationship between input potentials \$V_{IN1}\$, \$V_{IN2}\$ and output \$V_{OUT}\$ is:

$$ V_{OUT} = V_{IN2} \left( 1 + \frac{R_4}{R_3} \right) - V_{IN1} \frac{R_4}{R_3} $$

Since supply potentials do not appear in that equation, their asymmetry has nothing to do with the offset. All they can do in this system is limit the maximum and minimum possible output.

From the equation, it's pretty obvious that source V2 will cause an offset, as will any DC component of signal V1, and both will be subject to gain depending on the values of R3 and R4.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. My intention is to simulate exactly the section of the schematic indicated in the link above. That's why I added R5 and R6. For R1, R2 I tried to simulate a 10K Potentiometer. From the equation you present it makes sense that V2 is causing the offset, but that's for an Op Amp without input rails, right? Should I disregard the rails in my simulation?

Comment: @Facu Unless you have some input that is also a function of the power supply, you can disregard the supply. You don't, so the only effect the supplies have on the output is to constrain it to some maximum or minimum.